# Maximum Depth of N-ary Tree - swift

Tags: swift, recursion, tree

https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-depth-of-n-ary-tree/

I've already solved this through other ways. I'm just trying to resolve it through this code. Trying to figure out what's incorrect for this. It currently returns incorrect results:

```
class Solution {
    func maxDepth(_ root: Node?) -> Int {
        guard let node = root else { return 0 }
        return node.children.map(maxDepth).max() ?? 0 + 1
    }
}
```

Helper class if you wanted to test this on Xcode:

```
class Node {
    var value: Int
    var children: [Node] = []
    weak var parent: Node?
    
    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
    func add(child: Node) {
        children.append(child)
        child.parent = self
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let one = Node(value: 1)
let two = Node(value: 2)
let three = Node(value: 3)

one.add(child: two)
two.add(child: three)
print("res", maxDepth(one)) // returns: 2. Expected: 3
```

I'm always returning `2` actually. Not sure why...

Comment: What is the problem? Does it not compile? Wrong results? Runtime crash?

Comment: Sorry. Incorrect results.

Comment: A self-contained [mcve] with input data, actual output and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: Added input and out

Comment: Start with a tree consisting of a single node without children – can you see the problem? – This is a logic problem, not a Swift problem.

Comment: My brain is going in loops. Yeah I realize it's incorrect if it's just a single node. And I'd need to change it `node.children.map(maxDepth).max() ?? 0) + 1` Is that what you're recommending? That doesn't fix the whole problem though...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237676/discussion-between-martin-r-and-honey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shout out to Martin for helping me figure this out.

Pro tip. For such leetcode style questions. The dumbest/simplest tests are the best.

The line below has 2 mistakes:

```
return node.children.map(maxDepth).max() ?? 1 + 1
```

- The `??` is defaulting it to `0 + 1`. Wrap the `??` in a parenthesis
- The default should actually be `0`. Not `1`

So just do:

```
return (node.children.map(maxDepth).max() ?? 0) + 1
```

I made that mistake because I almost never have any arithmetic operations after the `??` ‍♂️